# Django XML failed to load external entity

Tags: python, django

I'm receiving a param called xml that contains an xml document. this is what I have tried...

```
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector, etree
from lxml.etree import fromstring

if request.POST:

    parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True, recover=True)
    h = etree.parse(request.POST['xml'], parser)

    return HttpResponse(h)
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error] IOError: Error reading file '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error] <delivery_receipt>
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error]     <version>1.1</version>
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error]     <msisdn>447777111111</msisdn>
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error]     <submission_ref>12345678901234567890123456789012</submission_ref>
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error]     <status>Delivered</status>
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error]     <reason>4</reason>
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error]     <gmt_timestamp>20130405095100</gmt_timestamp>
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error]     <retry>0</retry>
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error] </delivery_receipt>': failed to load external entity "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error] <delivery_receipt>
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error]     <version>1.1</version>
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error]     <msisdn>447777111111</msisdn>
[Fri Apr 05 09:50:13 2013] [error]     <submission_ref>12345678901234567890123456789012</submission_ref>
```

etc

any ideas? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.POST` returns unicode strings by default. The next problem you are having is related to the encoding your supplying isn't matching the declared encoding in the document you're supplying.

```
doc = request.POST.get('xml','')
if not doc:
  raise Exception()
h = etree.XML(doc.encode('ascii'), parser)
```

Comment: Hi this gives Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported :(

Answer (score 1):

`etree.parse` expects a filename (or a file object). There's no file named `<all your xml>`.

You need to feed the XML to the parser:

```
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector, etree
from lxml.etree import fromstring

if request.POST:

    parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True, recover=True)
    parser.feed(request.POST['xml'])
    h = parser.close()
    ...
```

Or use `fromstring` or `XML` functions.

```
h = fromstring(request.POST['xml'], parser=parser)
```

or

```
h = etree.XML(request.POST['xml'], parser=parser)
```

[The lxml.etree tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#parsing-from-strings-and-files)

Comment: Hi, @Pavel Anossov thanks for the reply, I tried this but got "Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported" with fromstring function.

Comment: `etree.parse` will also take URLs.

Comment: Hi @ MattH yes it seems to give the same error: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. but as you stated seems to do this same.

Comment: Does your xml include encoding declaration , if yes then may be thats the problem , Have a look at this https://gist.github.com/karlcow/3258330